# gluLookAt not working properly after drawing shapes

Tags: c++, opengl

I am really confused by how `gluLookAt` and `glOrtho` or `gluPersective` work together. Here is the problem.

I draw a 2D triangle and a 2D pentagon in the z-axis of -5.

```
//pentagon
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);

//Triangle
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
```

And Then I define my camera position (0,0,-10) and perspective

```
//Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
gluLookAt(0, 0, -10, 0, 0, -200, 0, 1, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective

//Set the camera perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the camera
gluPerspective(45.0,                  //The camera angle
    (double)w / (double)h, //The width-to-height ratio
    1.0,                   //The near z clipping coordinate
    5.2);                //The far z clipping coordinate
```

Based on my understanding, I can see nothing in the scene. Because objects are defined in the -5 z-axis, however, the camera is at -10 z-axis, and it looks into negative z-axis. Thus, the object should be behind the camera. But why I can still see the objects in the scene?
[image]

Similarly, I can still see the object when I define my camera at postive 5 at look towards positive z-axis. Why?

Another question is why I can see the objects after I set the far z clipping coordinate to 5?

Anyone can explain this?

My full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //Needed for "exit" function
//Include OpenGL header files, so that we can use OpenGL
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

//Called when a key is pressed
void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, //The key that was pressed
  int x, int y) {    //The current mouse coordinates
  switch (key) {
  case 27: //Escape key
    exit(0); //Exit the program
  }
}

//Initializes 3D rendering
void initRendering() {
  //Makes 3D drawing work when something is in front of something else
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

//Called when the window is resized
void handleResize(int w, int h) {
  //Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

  gluLookAt(0, 0, -10, 0, 0, -200, 0, 1, 0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective

  //Set the camera perspective
  glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the camera
  gluPerspective(45.0,                  //The camera angle
    (double)w / (double)h, //The width-to-height ratio
    1.0,                   //The near z clipping coordinate
    5.2);                //The far z clipping coordinate
}

//Draws the 3D scene
void drawScene() {
  //Clear information from last draw
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
  glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective

  glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates

  //Trapezoid
  glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);

  glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates

  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //Begin triangle coordinates

  //Pentagon
  glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

  glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

  glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);

  //Triangle
  glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);

  glEnd(); //End triangle coordinates

  glutSwapBuffers(); //Send the 3D scene to the screen
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  //Initialize GLUT
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(400, 400); //Set the window size

  //Create the window
  glutCreateWindow("Basic Shapes - videotutorialsrock.com");
  initRendering(); //Initialize rendering

  //Set handler functions for drawing, keypresses, and window resizes
  glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
  glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
  glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);

  glutMainLoop(); //Start the main loop.  glutMainLoop doesn't return.
  return 0; //This line is never reached
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example so that we can copy and paste it to compile and see the exact same results that you get.

Comment: note that using `glMatrixMode`, `glVertex3f` et. al. are all deprecated: you should define a vertex buffer object and submit the camera matrix to your shader - that way teaches you to do the right thing from the start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saying:

> I draw a 2D triangle and a 2D pentagon in the z-axis of -5
>   ...
>   And Then I define my camera position (0,0,-10) and perspective

If that is really the order you're doing the operations in, then that's the culprit. OpenGL is a command-based API, not a scene graph. Calling `glVertex(x, y, z)` does not mean "there is a vertex with coordinates `x, y, z` in the scene." It means "*now* go and draw a verex on coordinates `x, y, z`." This means the vertex is transformed by the modelview and projection matrix active *at the time of the `glVertex()` call.*

In other words, you issue the vertices with the default modelview and projection matrices, so they get drawn on the screen normally. Then you change the modelview and projection; if you then went on to issue any more vertices, they would be transformed by these new modelview and projection values. But the ones issued previously are already on the screen and unaffected.

In other words, remove these two lines from your draw function:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective
```

The comments seem to indicate the issue rather well.

---

The most common setup is to define the projection matrix in the resize hook (as it depends on the aspect ratio), and the view matrix (=camera position and orientation) in the draw function, *before* issuing any render commands.

As @datenwolf correctly pointed out in comments, this is the common setup for *single view* rendering. If you have more than one viewport, each of them will probably need a different projection matrix, in which case you would set up the projection matrix along with the view matrix in rendering code, before issuing primitives.

Comment: Thank you so much. So do you mean I should change the modelview and projection at first and should not change glMatrixMode anymore in the drawScene() ? I thought  GL_MODELVIEW and GL_PROJECTION will not affect each other.

Comment: @Diame `GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION` indeed do not affect each other, but the camera position (`gluLookAt`) should be stored in `GL_MODELVIEW` (the "view" part). Normally, you'd set up the projection in the resize hook, and the view in the render hook, before issuing any vertices.

Comment: Actually setting the projection matrix in the resize hook has its fair share of problems and should be avoided. As soon as you're fiddling with multiple viewports (think minimap or think top-left-right-perspective view) doing projection setup in the resize hook will bite you bad. Instead the projection matrix should be set right before the drawing commands that require that particular projection.